# Splitting Earth Wire in Attic for Light

Tags: electrical, lighting

I moved into a new home and found the downstairs light fittings all have earth wires leading into them, but only one of the upstairs fittings has.

Is it safe to split the single earth wire in the attic and feed it to a room for a new metal light fitting?

If so, would a pigtail be the right way to go about it?

Comment: Can you include a picture of where you would splice into the earth, ground?

Comment: What is the ampacity of the breakers in question?  What is the wire size of the various circuits?  Any aluminum involved? (not a problem per se but it affects wire size).

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Can you post photos of the insides of the fittings involved?

Answer (score 1):

In the US code was recently changed so that if your equipment is fed from the same panel you can take an appropriately sized ground to the ungrounded circuit.
I usually find lighting circuits on 15 amp all receptacles on 20 amp. 
If your lighting circuit is a 15 amp breaker you can tap any ground , if a 20 amp circuit you need to find a 20 amp, and you can use a receptacle or any larger ground to ground this fixture.

Comment: I'm not doubting you at all on this code change, Ed, but would you quote it so I can use it in the future if necessary? I've got a lot of old, ungrounded circuits in my house, and I'd love to buy a spool of #12 and run grounds everywhere I possibly can. Can a change in NEC 201x be used to allow this when AHJ is on NEC 200x? _Heads off into "whole new question" territory..._

Comment: See 250.130.C in the NEC , non grounding receptacle replacement or branch circuit extensions. What state are you in ? This was approved in the 17 code but I think it was new in the 14 code.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I'm in IN - we're on 2008 or 09 "with amendments"...

Comment: I did check they you are on 08 code they are working on 17 but with no date according to the NEC. I would check with your inspector since the 14 code allowed it it makes sense since grounding conductors are not current carrying and it makes old installs safer they may allow the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Ed! Greatly appreciated! _shoulda made a whole new question out of this..._